# How to Execute Queries against MongoDB Client Connection Correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await

When trying to execute a query (insertOne) against a MongoDB database in Node.JS I am getting the error:

```
/* *Note that the connect to [object Object] is me logging that the connection is created*/

Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
Connected to [object Object]
(node:58480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Cannot use a session that has ended
```

I have a function that creates a connection and accepts a callback function.  After the conneciton is created, the callback function is called.  The callback that I am supposed to be executing receives a collection and a document that is to be inserted to collection.  I have verified that the collection and document variables are correct.  It also appears that the connect function is actually connecting but I receive the error:

```
(node:58480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Cannot use a session that has ended
```

I have seen from [the mongodb documentation that the insertOne method needs to use await; however, when using that, I received an error stating cannot use it with a function that is not asynchronous](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/insertOne/).  For some reason, the logic below does not work.  No records are inserted into the databse at all but it does seem to create connections (logged by this line:  `` console.log( `Connected to ${ state.db }` ); ``)

This is my logic:

```
const { MongoClient, ObjectID } = require('mongodb');
// Environment Config
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require( '../config' )[ env ];
const dbConfig = config.database;

const state = {
    db: null
};

const getPrimaryKey = _id => ObjectID( _id );
const getDB = () => state.db;

const getConnectionString = () => {
    const protocol = dbConfig.protocol;
    const host = dbConfig.host;
    const port = dbConfig.port;
    return `${ protocol }://${ host }:${ port }`;
};



async function connect( callback ){
    if( getDB() ){
        callback();
    } else {
        const connectionString = getConnectionString();
        const client = new MongoClient(
            connectionString, dbConfig.options
        );

        try {
            await client.connect();
            state.db = client.db( dbConfig.db );
            console.log( `Connected to ${ state.db }` );
            callback();
        } catch ( exception ) {
            console.error( exception );
        } finally {
            client.close();
        }
    }
};


function insertDocument( collectionName, document ){
    function callback(){
        const db = getDB();
        const commandText = `${ db }.${ collectionName }.insertOne(${ document })`;
        const dbCollection = db.collection( collectionName );
        //const result = await dbCollection.insertOne( document ); //results in await is only valid in async funciton
        const result = dbCollection.insertOne( document );
        const resultText = `${ result.insertedCount } documents were inserted with the _id: ${ result.insertedId }`;
        const returnText = `Command: ${ commandText }; Result: ${ resultText }`;
        return returnText;
    }
    
    connect( callback );
}



module.exports = {
    getDB
    ,connect
    ,getPrimaryKey
    ,insertDocument
}
```